# All MySQL Tables with excluding via Bash

Tags: mysql, bash, escaping, sh

(Sorry for my bad English)

I want to select all Table Names in my MySQL Database, but exclude 2 Tables, and then work with these data in bash...

**BUT** when I try these Code, there is a Sort of Escaping Problem i think, is there any other possibilty to execute the Query and Catch its Output in the DBS Variable?

```
#/bin/bash
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=toor

DBS="$(mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -Bse 'SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS Database FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN('mysql', 'information_schema');')"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try storing the SQL string into its own variable, and echoing that into the mysql client:

```
#/bin/bash
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=toor

SQL_STRING="SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS db FROM information_schema.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN ('mysql', 'information_schema');"
# Pipe the SQL into mysql
DBS=$(echo $SQL_STRING | mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -Bs)

# Display your result
echo $DBS
```

Note, I also changed the `AS Database` to `AS db` since `DATABASE` is a MySQL reserved keyword which would have to be enclosed in backquotes.  I didn't want to mess around with getting those escaped properly in Bash.... Easier just to use a different alias.

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. The alias wasn't important in this place

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed single quotes in a single quoted string. Try:

```
DBS="$(mysql -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASS -Bse "SELECT SCHEMA_NAME AS Database FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMA_NAME NOT IN('mysql', 'information_schema');")"
```

The "inner" double quotes are OK because the parentheses indicate a new subshell.

Comment: Tried that one too, but got some Error's

Comment: @zirrka, such as ... ?? Details are important.